# bond0: interface ens192 is not defined

Tags: networking, netplan

I installed ubuntu 18.04, I trying to configure bond interface

```
network:
   bonds:
       bond0:
           addresses: [10.11.6.119/24]
           gateway4: 10.11.6.1
           nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
           interfaces:
           - ens192
           - ens160
           parameters:
               lacp-rate: fast
               mode: 802.3ad
               transmit-hash-policy: layer2
       ethernets:
           ens160:
               addresses: []
               dhcp4: false
               dhcp6: false
           ens192:
               addresses: []
               dhcp4: false
               dhcp6: false
version: 2
```

I see the following error after applying the settings

```
root@admin:~# netplan apply
Error in network definition /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 8 column 13: bond0: interface ens192 is not defined
```

But ens192 exist:

```
    root@admin:~# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:94:b5:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:94:c0:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm a newbie.

Comment: I think the lines following `interfaces:` should be indented.

Comment: I wrote  'interfaces: [ens160, ens192]' as follows. The result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Comments do not allow me to format this well, so I present this as a preliminary answer. I indented (moved to the right) the two lines with the names of the interfaces. Also, I think the last line `version: 2` ought to be indented.

```
network:
   bonds:
       bond0:
           addresses: [10.11.6.119/24]
           gateway4: 10.11.6.1
           nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
           interfaces:
               - ens192                    <--- changed
               - ens160                    <--- changed
           parameters:
               lacp-rate: fast
               mode: 802.3ad
               transmit-hash-policy: layer2
       ethernets:
           ens160:
               addresses: []
               dhcp4: false
               dhcp6: false
           ens192:
               addresses: []
               dhcp4: false
               dhcp6: false
    version: 2                            <--- changed
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was really in lines.

Comment: I think the `ethernets` block needs to have the same indent level as the `bonds` block rather than the `bond0` block.

Answer (score 0):

Your Netplan YAML file is not configured correctly. The `bonds` and `ethernets` blocks need to be at the same level.

Also, I don't see the `renderer` tag in your file. You don't state whether your system is a Server or Desktop installation. If it's a Server install, then you would include `renderer: networkd` as shown below. Otherwise, if this is a Desktop install, they you would change the line to `renderer: NetworkManager`.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    ens192:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bonds:
    bond0:
      addresses: [10.11.6.119/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      gateway4: 10.11.6.1
      interfaces:
        - ens160
        - ens192
      parameters:
        lacp-rate: fast
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2
```

> **NOTE** In Ubuntu 18.04, `gateway4` is still correct. But in later Ubuntu
> versions, `gateway4` has been deprecated, so you would want to use
> `routes` instead. See [Netplan YAML Configuration](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/) for info.

After configuration, apply the changes:

`sudo netplan try`

Additionally, you need to install the bonding driver:

`sudo modprobe bonding`

Verify driver installation:

`sudo lsmod | grep bonding`

Enter the following to load driver automatically on boot:

`echo 'bonding' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`